# "Круг людей, к которому примкнула" не требует вмешательства?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование

> Я узнала о понятии «альтернативное акушерство» и начала всё глубже
>   погружаться в эту тему, пока не нашла круг людей, к которому
>   примкнула.

То есть обязательно ли согласование по последнему слову? (Правда, я не знаю, согласование ли это иль ещё какой-нито способ грамотно сложить слова...)

**Расширенный контекст:**

> Я приверженец так называемых «мягких родов». Сейчас вокруг такого
>   подхода существует масса спекуляций, но мне повезло тогда прочесть
>   труд замечательного французского врача, изначально хирурга, который
>   работал в Алжире, Гвинее и который развернул европейскую акушерскую
>   практику в сторону естественного рождения. Книга Мишеля Одена
>   «Возрождённые роды» оказала непосредственное влияние на мою жизнь. Мой
>   ребёнок появился на свет дома. Не могу сказать, что я склонна к
>   оригинальности. Напротив, изложенные в этой книге идеи были, на мой
>   взгляд, весьма рациональны и оттого захватили меня. Обнаружить похожее
>   на описанное Оденом родильное отделение в России 90-х я тогда не
>   смогла, зато узнала о понятии «альтернативное акушерство» и начала всё
>   глубже погружаться в эту тему, пока не нашла круг людей, к которому
>   примкнула. Здесь я познакомилась со своей будущей акушеркой, в
>   обязанности которой входило в первую очередь воспитание родителей.
>   Наши встречи проходили два-три раза в неделю на протяжении семи
>   месяцев и делились на теорию и практику.

Comment: _...и начала всё глубже погружаться в эту тему, пока не нашла..._ === А как нашла, так что, уже перестала погружаться? По-моему, надо вначале разобраться со смыслом. Понять, что автор хотел  сказать.  Нужен обширный контекст.

Comment: Будет. Только ответьте, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Обнаружить похожее на описанное Оденом родильное отделение в России
>   90-х я тогда не смогла, зато узнала о понятии «альтернативное
>   акушерство» и начала всё глубже погружаться в эту тему, **пока не нашла**
>   круг людей, к которому примкнула. Здесь я познакомилась со своей
>   будущей акушеркой...

Из комментария в этой теме:

> Круг людей - таких же приверженцев «альтернативного акушерства».

Я бы заменил *"пока не нашла"* в приведённой выше цитате на *"вскоре нашла", "спустя какое-то время нашла"* или на что-либо подобное.

Как вариант:

*Обнаружить похожее на описанное Оденом родильное отделение в России 90-х я тогда не смогла, зато узнала о понятии «альтернативное акушерство» и начала всё глубже погружаться в эту тему.  Спустя какое-то время нашла круг людей — таких же, как и я, приверженцев «альтернативного акушерства», — к которому и примкнула. Здесь **я** познакомилась со своей будущей акушеркой…*

**P. S.**

Последнее "я", на мой взгляд, лучше выкинуть.

Answer (score 2):

Грамматической ошибки нет:...начала всё глубже погружаться в эту тему, пока не нашла круг людей (какой круг?), к которому примкнула.

Придаточное предложение не обязательно согласуется с последним словом главного. А вот содержательно изменить бы надо, как сказал Alex_ander, или заменить "круг людей" на "круг единомышленников", иначе смысл несколько затемнен.

Answer (score 1):

Надо бы пояснить, какое отношение имеет "круг людей" к тому самому "понятию" (напр. *соответствующий* круг людей - а не какой-то такой, в котором нашла спасение от новых, пугающих понятий) и хоть как-то обозначить, что именно *сначала* нашла, а *потом* уже примкнула (напр. *к которому **и** примкнула*), чтобы исключить толкование "нашла-таки, что это был за круг людей, к которому давеча невольно примкнула".

Comment: Круг людей - таких же приверженцев «альтернативного акушерства», как лирическая героиня.

Comment: Догадаться можно, но из текста это не следует - кто ж её знает, при таких альтернативных интересах?

Comment: Но это не ответ на вопрос, вынесенный в шапку.

Comment: Вмешательства - требует (по минимуму - одно доп. слово + 1 буква).